# How to add multiple input box dynamically with dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am having this problem which I can't find the solution to.
1) I have a dropdown list which the data is pull in from a json file
2) When the user selects a item I want to dynamically add a input box without a button.

Got a jQuery code but wanted to do it the angular way, but read that ng-Change is not the same as jquery .change?

Can anyone help or point me into the right direction of how to do this.

HTML

```
    <div class="main-content__right" ng-controller="QuestionController">
      <div ng-repeat="element in questionList">
        <fieldset>
          <div id="add-more" class="well">
            <div class="field">
              <div style="width:100%;" class="dropdown">
                <select name="{{options.name}}" id="select" data-ng-model="formData" 
data-ng-options="options as options.label for options in element.inputElement | orderBy:'label'" 
ng-change="onCategoryChange(formData)">
                  <option value="" data-id="null" disabled="" selected="">Select an item...</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


          {{formData}}
        </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("cab", []);
  app.controller('QuestionController', function($scope) {
    var $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.questionList = [{
      "sectionTitle": "Travel",
      "subTitle": "How much do you spend on these items for your car?",
      "inputType": "select",
      "inputElement": [{
          "label": "Public transport",
          "name": "travelOutgoing",
          "helpInfo": "include train journeys",
          "type": "select"
        }, {
          "label": "Taxis",
          "name": "travelOutgoing",
          "type": "select"
        }, {
          "label": "Bicycle",
          "name": "travelOutgoing",
          "helpInfo": "general running costs such as repair or rental",
          "type": "select"
        }, {
          "label": "Car rental",
          "name": "travelOutgoing",
          "helpInfo": "include fuel, parking charges and tolls",
          "type": "select"
        }

      ]
    }];

    $scope.onCategoryChange = function () {};

  });
```

can be found on http://plnkr.co/edit/PPDYKjztPF528yli9FbN?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller function needs to add each selection to an array on scope:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('QuestionController', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = [];
  $scope.selectedValue = {};

  $scope.questionList = [{
    "sectionTitle": "Travel",
    "subTitle": "How much do you spend on these items for your car?",
    "inputType": "select",
    "inputElement": [{
    "label": "Public transport",
    "name": "travelOutgoing",
    "helpInfo": "include train journeys",
    "type": "select"
  }, {
    "label": "Taxis",
    "name": "travelOutgoing",
    "type": "select"
  }, {
    "label": "Bicycle",
    "name": "travelOutgoing",
    "helpInfo": "general running costs such as repair or rental",
    "type": "select"
  }, {
    "label": "Car rental",
    "name": "travelOutgoing",
    "helpInfo": "include fuel, parking charges and tolls",
    "type": "select"
     }]
  }];

  $scope.onCategoryChange = function(selectedItem) {
    $scope.formData.push(selectedItem)
  };

});
```

Then you can use an ng-repeat to render all of the items in formData.

**HTML**

```
  <fieldset>
    <div id="add-more" class="well">
      <div class="field">
        <div style="width:100%;" class="dropdown">
          <select name="{{options.name}}" id="select" data-ng-model="selectedValue" data-ng-options="options as options.label for options in element.inputElement | orderBy:'label'" ng-change="onCategoryChange(selectedValue)">
            <option value="" data-id="null" disabled="" selected="">Select an item...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="item in formData track by $index">
        <input ng-model="item.label" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: ok that cool that works, but how I would get it add another and another currently it overwrites it??? maybe in a ng-repeat would that work?

Comment: Ng-repeat is a possibility. Depends on what the model that you are binding to looks like. Can you update the controller code to include the model?  Then I could give you some guidance.

Comment: if I am correct my form elements will be bind to this variable var formData = {}; Still quite new to angular so might of missed a few steps

Comment: Do you expect formData to remain an object or could it be an array of objects?

Comment: I could be an array of objects

Comment: @NiseNise - Ok.  I'm going to change my answer, so you should probably edit your question to state that you want to add multiple input boxes so that anyone else reading this doesn't get confused by the answer.